# Binary Tree Node Class reference

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, nodes

I am learning binary tree and I am trying to understand why is `Node left` calling `class Node` again.

Eg:

```
class Node
{
   Node left, right;
   int data;
}
```

Why is `Node` calling `Node` and why it isn't int Node.

Comment: `Node` is not calling `Node`. Those are just field declarations. An instance of the `Node` class simply has reference to a left and right `Node`, which are in turn instances of the `Node` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary tree is simply a structure that contains 0 to 2 references to the same type of object linked together. For example, this poorly drawn diagram:

```
  10
 /  \
1    5
    / \
   3   6
```

10 is a `Node` with:

- `left` references a `Node` with `value` 1.
- `right` references to a `Node` with `value` 5.

The other nodes are similar.

Answer (score 1):

The fields `left` and `right` simply may contain references to other `Node` instances. They are not called class, simply reference-typed fields.

With such a setup, you can build up a binary tree, as now each `Node` can contain a value - `int data` - and a reference to the root node of the left sub-tree - `Node left` - and a reference to the root node of the right sub-tree - `Node right`.

Comment: what does reference to the root node mean?

Comment: Sorry. If you do not know these terms, you should go and read some beginning tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

This is not calling, this is [member declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) and those are fields, if it was just `int node` we dont have any reference to node's childs so we need to have fields of type `node` and because of it is binary tree we need to have `left child` and `right childs`.

Comment: This is not calling ?? What do you mean by that?

Comment: You dont call a class field, it is just declaration, in the parent node you have child node, so you could find child node. suppose node a have two child a and b, how could you know that if a where just an integer? you must have the child node in the parent node to know that. That is just it.